# SQL create a conditional sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server, sequence

I want to create a conditional int field called **Sequence** for each group of IDs.

The value 1 is given to **Sequence** for the first occurrence of a condition, otherwise increment the last count by 1. There are finite list of values for the field condition as illustrated below.

For a new group of ID, Sequence should initialise and start counting from 1.

| ID | Date | Condition | Seq |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 01Jun14 | AAAAAAAAA | 1 |
| 01 | 02Jun14 | AAAAAAAAA | 2 |
| 01 | 03Jun14 | BBBBBBBBB | 1 |
| 01 | 04Jun14 | BBBBBBBBB | 2 |
| 01 | 05Jun14 | AAAAAAAAA | 3 |
| 01 | 06Jun14 | BBBBBBBBB | 3 |
| 01 | 07Jun14 | EEEEEEEEE | 1 |
| 02 | 01Jun14 | AAAAAAAAA | 1 |
| 02 | 02Jun14 | CCCCCCCCC | 1 |
| 02 | 03Jun14 | CCCCCCCCC | 2 |
| 02 | 04Jun14 | BBBBBBBBB | 1 |
| 02 | 05Jun14 | AAAAAAAAA | 2 |
| 02 | 06Jun14 | BBBBBBBBB | 2 |
| 03 | 01Jun14 | FFFFFFFFF | 1 |
| 03 | 02Jun14 | AAAAAAAAA | 1 |
| 03 | 03Jun14 | AAAAAAAAA | 2 |
| 03 | 04Jun14 | CCCCCCCCC | 1 |

Comment: what have you tried ? This looks like a job for [row_number()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: I have tried ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION by ID ORDER BY ID, Condition) as Seq. This gives just a row number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `partition by condition, id` in your row_number so that the row_numbers start at 1 for each combination of condition and id.
I have created a table with your required numbering so as to check that the calulated values are what you need.

> ```
> select
>   ID,
>   d "Date" ,
>   Condition,
>   Seq seq_required,
>   row_number() over (partition by condition, id order by d) seq_calculated
> from t
> order by id, d
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | Date       | Condition | seq_required | seq_calculated
> -: | :--------- | :-------- | -----------: | -------------:
>  1 | 2014-06-01 | AAAAAAAAA |            1 |              1
>  1 | 2014-06-02 | AAAAAAAAA |            2 |              2
>  1 | 2014-06-03 | BBBBBBBBB |            1 |              1
>  1 | 2014-06-04 | BBBBBBBBB |            2 |              2
>  1 | 2014-06-05 | AAAAAAAAA |            3 |              3
>  1 | 2014-06-06 | BBBBBBBBB |            3 |              3
>  1 | 2014-06-07 | EEEEEEEEE |            1 |              1
>  2 | 2014-06-01 | AAAAAAAAA |            1 |              1
>  2 | 2014-06-02 | CCCCCCCCC |            1 |              1
>  2 | 2014-06-03 | CCCCCCCCC |            2 |              2
>  2 | 2014-06-04 | BBBBBBBBB |            1 |              1
>  2 | 2014-06-05 | AAAAAAAAA |            2 |              2
>  2 | 2014-06-06 | BBBBBBBBB |            2 |              2
>  3 | 2014-06-01 | FFFFFFFFF |            1 |              1
>  3 | 2014-06-02 | AAAAAAAAA |            1 |              1
>  3 | 2014-06-03 | AAAAAAAAA |            2 |              2
>  3 | 2014-06-04 | CCCCCCCCC |            1 |              1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=69311908d9774747bd3260b269e76d5d)*

Comment: Thank you so much. Your code worked beautifully.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments by Squirrel, this is a job for row number
Basically

```
Seq = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, CONDITION ORDER BY DATE ASC)
```

If you need to incorporate this into your code while Insert statement, you'd do something like this

```
DECLARE @Seq INT
SELECT @Seq= ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, CONDITION  ORDER BY DATE ASC) FROM <yourtable> WHERE ID=@ID AND CONDITION= @condition 

INSERT INTO <yourtable> VALUES
(@ID, @date, @condition, ISNULL(@Seq,1))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `dense_rank()` should do the trick.

```
select 
ID,
[Date],
Condition,
dense_RANK() OVER(PARTITION by ID ORDER BY [Date]) as Seq
from Yourtable
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID,Condition,COUNT(con) as seq FROM "your table name" GROUP BY con

SELECT ID,Condition,COUNT(con) as seq FROM "your table name" where ID=1 GROUP BY con
```

desc:

1- for counting all type of Conditional in table

2- for counting each type of Conditional in each group of IDs